# Submitting form via javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, forms

I have a page where the user gets directed to if they want to edit some text which was on the previous screen. Once they have finished editing the form data it gets submitted for validation to javascript, this is the form:

```
<form id='editpost' action='' method='post' >
Your Post:<br/>
<input type='hidden' name='' value='""'>
Title: <input type='text' name='' value='""'/><br/>
<textarea name='' cols='100' rows='100'>""</textarea>
<br/><input type=submit value='Submit' name='' onclick='return validate(document.forms[0]);'><input type=submit value='Cancel' name=''> 
</form>
}
```

I check for values being entered in the appropriate boxes by using javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(F) {      
    var post = F;
    var title = F;
    post = post.trim();
    title = title.trim();
    if(post.length == 0) {
        alert("This is blank");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if(title.length == 0) {
            var agree=confirm("Really?");
            if (agree) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When the form is eventually submitted some data gets updated in a mysql database with the data from the form and the user gets redirected to the page to view it. What I want to be able to do is submit the form via a post method in javascript, this is to stop the user turning their javascript off and potentially enter blank bodys into the db. I'm really not sure how to do this though.

Comment: You should NEVER, EVER, rely only on client-side validation. You should also perform server-side validation too!!!!

Comment: if they turn off JavaScript, how will your code run?

Comment: I am going to implement both but this is the harder for me as I've not really dealt with javascript before.

Comment: he does need server-side validation but most sites use some client-side validation to speed up the process of helping the user through the form.  He shouldn't have to resubmit to the server every time the user misses a field.

Comment: People who turn off javascript should expect stuff to break.

Comment: @antisanity: Which explains why all large websites function perfectly fine without JS.

Comment: @Hello71: You mean all those large sites which leverage async requests, long-polling, etc?

Comment: @antisanity: Because one of the largest JavaScript-powered applications, Gmail, doesn't work with JS turned off. It's not like they have a basic HTML view or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your submit button on the page should be a dummy button that only calls your validation function. Then to submit just say document.getElementById('editpost').submit(); from your code. (if my memory fails me you might try capitalizing that S on submit)

Hope this helps.

edit:

```
<form id='editpost' action='editPost.php' method='post' >
...
<br/><input type=button value='Submit' name='alterPost' onclick='validateForm(document.forms[0]);'><input type=submit value='Cancel' name='no'> 
</form>
```

then in your javascript, instead of returning a value

```
...
// if it's valid
F.submit();
...
// if it's not valid
// show the user a message explaining why
...
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. **None** of the above will work if the user has Javascript turned off - wasn't that the question?

Answer (score 1):

> *What I want to be able to do is submit the form via a post method in javascript, this is to stop the user turning their javascript off and potentially enter blank*

What you actually need is **server side** (not client side/Javascript) validation in order to prevent "invalid data" (however you define it) from being sent/saved to your database.

If Javascript is turned off on the client (browser) **none** of your Javascript will run, the form will POST (or GET) to whatever action you define (editPost.php). You need to add validation code/handling to editPost.php